# Would completable future be better choice than parallel stream in this scenario

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, java-stream, completable-future

I am writing an API where I get a list of transactions with different product codes. I need to segregate these transactions based on product code in a map and then execute all the map contents parallelly. I am running some validations on these transactions and business logic for transactions is different based on product code. I am currently using parallel stream. The execution of transactions based on product code is different for instance if product code is abc then I will call a downstream api, if product code is xyz then I will call a different api like that. I want suggestion if using completable future rather that parallel stream would be more beneficial as implementation based on product code is different and unrelated. Here is my code so far.

```
public ContributionValidationResponse validateRequest(ContributionValidationRequest contributionValidationRequest) throws Exception {
        List<Contribution> contributions = contributionValidationRequest.getContributions();
        Map<ProductCode, List<Contribution>> contributionMap = contributions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Contribution::getProductCode));
        List<ContributionValidationResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        contributionMap.values().parallelStream().forEach(item-> {
            try {
                responseList.add(validateProduct.executeProductValidations(createProductRequest(contributionValidationRequest, item)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        //ContributionValidationResponse deductionValidationResponse = validateProduct.executeProductValidations(contributionValidationRequest);
        return aggregateResponses(responseList);
    }
    
    private ContributionValidationRequest createProductRequest(ContributionValidationRequest request, List<Contribution> list) {
        ContributionValidationRequest productRequest = new ContributionValidationRequest(request.getCustomerIdentifiers());
        productRequest.setContributions(list);
        productRequest.setEmployerId(request.getEmployerId());
        return productRequest;
    }
    
    private ContributionValidationResponse aggregateResponses(List<ContributionValidationResponse> responseList) {
        ContributionValidationResponse contributionValidationResponse = new ContributionValidationResponse();
        contributionValidationResponse.setCustomerIdentifiers(responseList.get(0).getCustomerIdentifiers());
        contributionValidationResponse.setContributions(new ArrayList<>());
        responseList.stream().forEach(item-> contributionValidationResponse.getContributions().addAll(item.getContributions()));
        return contributionValidationResponse;
    }
}
```